# ( Nuxt's Vue-router ) How to differentiate path ending with "/" and without

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Using the [`extendRoutes`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#extendroutes) attribute for nuxt's router, I am attempting to differentiate paths ending with a slash and paths that do not. This is due to how the CMS we are using handles paths.

I *could* differentiate them by distinguishing the overview page as a path ending in `/all` or `/overview`, but it's not ideal.

I have a `_slug.vue` on my pages directory

(Should match `/articles/some-article-1)`

And I have a route for the articles overview with nested categories.

(Should match `/articles/` `/articles/category/` and `/articles/category/category-of-category/`)

This appears to work,

```js
            routes.unshift({
                name: 'articles',
                path: '/articles/:category([^/]*/)',
                component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/-overview.vue')
            })
```

but raises an error:

Expected "category" to match "[^/]*/", but received "dfdf%2F

How do I properly match paths terminating in slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'articles',
      path: '/articles/:category',
      strict: true,
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/-overview.vue')
    },
   
   ...
  ]
})
```

```js
// or, for all routes
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    ...
  ],
  strict: true
})
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#sensitive-and-strict-route-options

Comment: It appears for nuxt2, using vue-router 3*, it is `pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true },`
I just didn't see it in the docs.
Thanks!